# Having two Page_Load without overriding

Tags: c#, asp.net, overriding, pageload

I have a class named `PageBase` inheriting from ASP.NET `Page`. I want to do something in `PageBase`'s `Page_Load`. All pages in my application have their logic done on their `Page_Load`. 
I'm thinking of a way that `Page_Load` of both of `PageBase` and other pages run without having to override `Page_Load` in pages. Is it possbile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just attach the Page_Load handler within constructor. This is how you do it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Your PageBase class.
/// </summary>
public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Page class.
    /// </summary>
    public Page()
    {
        this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Your Page Load
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">sender as object</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments</param>
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch
        {
             //handle the situation gracefully.
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Here's how it works.

`Load` is a public event declared in `System.Web.UI.Page` which is inherited in the PageBase class as it is. Since this is an event you can attach as many as handler on the event, each of them will be called/executed whenever the `Load` event is raised. In the `PageBase` class we are attaching an event-handler routine to the Load event. This is better way to do it instead of inheriting the OnLoad protected routine where you need to explicitly call the base version. When the actual Page object is created/instantiated the base class object is created first then the sub-class is instantiated, so when the PageBase object is constructed the event-handler is attached onto the Load event which will be called whenever the Page object fires the Load event.

Comment: Perhaps explain why Page_Load in his derived page classes will also still run.

Comment: @curious_geek: your solution worked as expected. many thanks.